# Error "qwebview_darwin.mm:261:24" at building qt 5.10.0 from Source for macOS 10.12.6

Tags: macos-sierra, qt5.10

I want to build the new Qt5.10.0 version from source for my macOS with version 10.12.6 (Sierra).

These errors occurred at the end of the build process:

```
qwebview_darwin.mm:261:24: error:
'loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:' is only available on macOS 10.11
or newer
[-Werror,-Wunguarded-availability]
[wkWebView loadFileURL:url.toNSURL()
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Headers/WKWebView.h:102:1: 
note: 
'loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:' has been explicitly marked
partial here
- (nullable WKNavigation *)loadFileURL:(NSURL *)URL allowingReadAccessToURL:(NSURL *)readAccessURL API_AVAILAB...
^
qwebview_darwin.mm:261:24: note: enclose
'loadFileURL:allowingReadAccessToURL:' in an @available check to
silence this warning

[wkWebView loadFileURL:url.toNSURL()


                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [.obj/debug/qwebview_darwin.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [debug-install] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-webview-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
make: *** [module-qtwebview-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

Maybe you have some tricks to handle this error. 
Do you know, what i have to do?
And how to bypass these errors?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this report on the Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65075) this appears to be fixed in 5.10.1 (and also 5.9.4), so pulling the new version should solve your and my problem without having to edit the Qt source

I can now confirm that the code in 5.10.1 is now guarded by

```
if (__builtin_available(macOS 10.11, iOS 9, *)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the call to `loadFileURL` in an `@available` check, like the following

```
if (@available(macOS 10.11, *)) {
    [wkWebView loadFileURL:url.toNSURL() allowingReadAccessToURL:QUrl(url.toString(QUrl::RemoveFilename)).toNSURL()];
}
```